# Converting row in timeseries data to column

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose that I have a timeseries like

```
In [41]: df = pd.DataFrame(dict(names=list('abcaabcabbcc'), vals=np.random.randint(0, 10, 12)), index
    ...: =pd.date_range('2017-03-01', periods=12))

In [42]: df
Out[42]: 
           names  vals
2017-03-01     a     2
2017-03-02     b     9
2017-03-03     c     6
2017-03-04     a     6
2017-03-05     a     5
2017-03-06     b     2
2017-03-07     c     3
2017-03-08     a     1
2017-03-09     b     1
2017-03-10     b     1
2017-03-11     c     1
2017-03-12     c     0
```

How can I convert the `names` row into the column headers, under which the corresponding `vals` are? e.g.

```
               a     b     c  
2017-03-01     2   nan   nan
2017-03-02   nan     9   nan
...
```

I have been playing around with `pd.melt` as well as trying to add the `names` to the index and then reset the index so that they become columns somehow, but I am very stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
print (pd.pivot(index=df.index, columns=df['names'], values=df['vals']))
```

Or:

```
print (df.set_index('names', append=True)['vals'].unstack())
names         a    b    c
2017-03-01  4.0  NaN  NaN
2017-03-02  NaN  0.0  NaN
2017-03-03  NaN  NaN  3.0
2017-03-04  8.0  NaN  NaN
2017-03-05  0.0  NaN  NaN
2017-03-06  NaN  0.0  NaN
2017-03-07  NaN  NaN  9.0
2017-03-08  6.0  NaN  NaN
2017-03-09  NaN  6.0  NaN
2017-03-10  NaN  0.0  NaN
2017-03-11  NaN  NaN  3.0
2017-03-12  NaN  NaN  9.0
```

---

```
print (df.reset_index().pivot_table(index='index', columns='names', values='vals'))
```

Comment: Ahh use a pivot table. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you can also use unstack():

```
In [12]: df.set_index('names', append=True).unstack('names')
Out[12]:
           vals
names         a    b    c
2017-03-01  1.0  NaN  NaN
2017-03-02  NaN  4.0  NaN
2017-03-03  NaN  NaN  5.0
2017-03-04  8.0  NaN  NaN
2017-03-05  8.0  NaN  NaN
2017-03-06  NaN  5.0  NaN
2017-03-07  NaN  NaN  7.0
2017-03-08  5.0  NaN  NaN
2017-03-09  NaN  7.0  NaN
2017-03-10  NaN  4.0  NaN
2017-03-11  NaN  NaN  3.0
2017-03-12  NaN  NaN  4.0
```

Comment: @jezrael, you are too fast :)

Comment: but double numpy .where today was faster ;)

Comment: I appreciate the friendly competition between you two, you've both helped me on many occasions :)